# The Historical Development of Nouns and Adjectives

Tags: etymology, nouns, adjectives

Historically speaking, were nouns derived from adjectives or were adjectives derived from nouns?  That is to say, as verbal communication developed which came first:  the noun, or the adjective?

Comment: Why are you assuming that one necessarily derives from the other in all situations?  Plus you’re asking some sort of Chomsky question about historical language acquisition ordering in general, not something that could possibly be about just English alone.

Comment: Probably this question is a good question for linguistic.se, here it is off-topic.

Comment: Many languages don't have adjectives. Plus, nobody knows how verbal communication developed, and if anybody tells you they do, don't believe them.

Comment: @John Lawler As an engineer, I am not an expert in linguistic; but it seems strange to me that it exisits languages whitout adjectives.

Comment: It depends on your definition of an adjective.

Comment: Exactly. The Romans didn't even have the category "adjective". They treated what we would call adjectives as nouns, because they had exactly the same inflections as nouns and could be used exactly like nouns. In Indonesian, what we call adjectives are just predicates, same as verbs.